# Notation orthogonal direct sum

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, direct-sum

Let $W_j\subseteq L²(ℝ)$ also Hilbertspaces. If I would like to show
$$L²(ℝ)=\overline{\oplus_{j\in ℤ}W_j},$$
can I instead show that 
$$L²(ℝ)=\overline{span\left(\bigcup\limits_{j\in \mathbb{Z}}^{}W_j\right)}?$$

Comment: It depends what $\oplus$ means: just direct sum, or direct sum plus orthogonality.

Comment: @daw The title says OP is considering an orthogonal direct sum.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy the title seems to have nothing to do with the post: 'Notation' versus 'Show something'

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A subspace is dense iff any function orthogonal to each element of the subspace is necessarily $0$. And a function is orthogonal to a union of subspaces iff it is orthogonal to their direct sum.

Comment: Thank you! So I belief you.

Answer (score 0):

No. The direct sum sign $\oplus$ usually includes some kind of unique decomposition of the base space into the subspaces. That is, if $V = U_1\oplus U_2$ then each element in $V$ can be *uniquely* decomposed into a sum of elements of $U_1$ and $U_2$.
Just proving $V=span( U_1\cup U_2)$ is not sufficient.

Comment: This answer is wrong.